# Trying to plot two continuous variables on seperate Y axis by specific factor

Tags: plot

I am trying to create a line plot for two different Y (continuous) variables on one plot, with each variable having a different Y axis but the same X-axis. I can do this using the following code:

twoord.plot(Yvariable1, Yvariable2, xlab="", ylab="", rylab="", main="", type="l")

However, there is a 3rd variable that is associated with the data that I have called "Location" (eg. north, south, east, etc...). This variable is a factor and there are hundreds of locations, so I would like to create this same plot for Yvariable 1 and Yvariable2 on differnt Y axis's for only the specific location of my interest. Is there anything I can add to this code so that I can call upon a specific factor within the variable Location? Or is there another way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone's interest, I think I found a work around to this question. You can subset teh data you are looking for using

Newname <- subset(maindataset, VariableName == "Factor Level")

Then, in the twoord function, you can just specify Yvariable1 and Yvariable 2 to be Newname$maindataset. Hope that helps anyone interested!